# Collapse (hide) code inside a function

Tags: code-review, cells, inline

I often use structures similar to the "func" below, however I would like to be able to "hide" the function definitions (similar to cell grouping using a group opener). I think an inline cell is the answer but I have had no success in implementing it.

```
func[this_][arg_] := this =Module[{f, g},
   f[x_] := x Sin[x];
   g[x_] := x^2 + x + 1;
   <|
     "x" -> arg,
     "f" :> f[this["x"]],
     "g" :> g[this["x"]]
   |>];
```

Answer (score 4):

> however I would like to be able to "hide" the function definitions

I recommend using [Mathematica's Eclipse workbench](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/?source=footer) for these things.
I am now switching all my development to it, since it also has a very nice debugger and many more advantages, too many to list here. It has all the features of the notebook in terms of code completion, etc.. plus more.

Do all you code writing inside the workbench as .m files, and use the notebook .nb file only to make the main calls to your functions, ie. as driver or for testing and other small code for trying things out.

Here is an example doing what you want inside the Wolfram workbench. There is a small + mark next to each function. If you click on it, it hides the code of the function. Click again, it open the code again.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139620/discussion-on-answer-by-nasser-collapse-hide-code-inside-a-function).